# External Schema access from Tenant DB for HANA XSA

Tags: hana

I am trying to access external schema data into HDI container of HANA XSA. When external schema is in SYSTEMDB , I can access the data . But, if I load data into external schema inside any tenant DB ,it does not work . After investigation, I found users related to my HDI container are created in SYSTEMDB but not in TenantDB and that is why when I use User Provided Service with tenant DB it does not work . Is there any way I can force my HDI container to store users inside tenant DB instead of SYSTEMDB

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recreated space and tenant DB and map them once again . Now, HDI users are getting created in tenant DB. Not sure, if I did some mistake in the first place.